# K Fold Cross validation

Tags: python, random-forest, cross-validation

I want to implement the cross validation in Random Forest Regressor in my data set. I want to know if my code is correct or not? Is this the way to cross validate?
Here is my sample data:

```
Wavelength    Phase_velocity     Shear_wave_velocity
1.50               202.69          240.73
1.68               192.72          240.73
1.79               205.54          240.73
........
```

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.model_selection import KFold,train_test_split,cross_val_score

    df = pd.read_csv("5.5-6.csv")
    df.head()

    X = df[['wavelength', 'phase velocity']]
    y = df['shear wave velocity']

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

    print (len(X_train),len(X_test),len(y_train),len(y_test))

    from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
    kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)

    rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=30000)
    rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    results = cross_val_score(rf, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold) #Cross validation on training set

    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

    print (rf.predict(X_test)) #array_output
    print (y_test)
    print (rf.score(X_test, y_test))
    y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
    print (mean_absolute_error(y_test,y_pred))

    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

    from math import sqrt

    rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred))

    print(rmse)
```

Comment: A random forest model generally does _not_ require cross validation.  The process of out of bag sampling implicitly cross validates the forest as it being built.  You should instead check things like the importance metrics of your RF model.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. And what about MLP Regressor, SVM, Logistic Regression? Does it require cross validation?

Comment: Yes...those probably _do_ require cross validation as part of the model-building process.

Comment: so is it okay if i put the above code for SVM for cross validation?

Comment: I've never worked with SVM using Python.  I can say that yes you should be using cross validation with SVM.